# How to increase width of box according to page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having hard time creating a progress bar which should increase its width as per the load of page.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var startTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd;
  var endTime = window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
  var loadTime = startTime - endTime;      

})
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="outerWidth">
    <div class="innerWidth">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outerWidth {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px; 
}

.innerWidth {
  background-color: #f00;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 0;
}
```

As per the code the width of innerWidth class is 0

Now two things I want to do.

- 1. Since I have a load time of page so how can I increase the innerWidth class width to 100% when page loads.
- 2. How can I display that time in percentage so that it should display 100% at the end of page loading is finished.

Again its a progress bar kind of program i'm looking for. which shows percentage also. But for any page load by calculating the page size or page load time. I don't know what way is correct.

Help Needed!

Comment: Have u tried to use Bootstrap progress bar?    http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress

Comment: How can you know how much time will your page take to load? Without this information you cannot show a %.

Comment: Dacklf see the loadTime variable it will show you the loading time of page.

Comment: @Sam  but loadTime knows the time it has taken to load the page when the page has finished loading. So what's the point then?

Comment: can you create the progress bar which shows the width incremently in percentage as per the loading of page in any color. Do you have any better way of doing this. thanks @Daclf

Comment: It's can't be done, how do you want to display the loading bar if the dom itself haven't load yet? And the loading bar is part of the dom.. Maybe if you use ajax to load portion of pages each time and load the loading bar with the first portion? But yeah would be complicated to implement it

Comment: @Sam You can only know the proportion of the time taken for the page to load when you know the time taken for the page to load, which you find out when the page has loaded. If you can code this bar, there's a Nobel prize in it for you.

Comment: let say the content is only shown when the DOM is fully loaded and till the DOM is loading we can show a progress bar like something is getting downloaded from server in percentage. I think ubisoft uses this functionality where I saw this or there are lot of websites on themeforest which use this technique.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know how much time the page will take to load. Because of that, you cannot show a percentage.

Some ideas:

- Load a small, lightweight and incomplete version of your page. Use AJAX to load the full version and show a [loading gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif) in the meantime.
- Show the [loading gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif) only and load the complete page via AJAX.
- If you are worried about the time that uses a given script (client side), show a [loading gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif) for the duration. And don't worry about the initial loading time.

Concerning a part of question, you can easily manage a progress bar with bootstrap or create one yourself. Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/n0v74rm8/1/).

```
function startProgress() {
    var curProg = 0;        
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        curProg = curProg + 5;
        $('#progBar').css('width', curProg + '%');
        if (curProg > 100) clearInterval(interval);
    }, 50)
}
```